# How to implement unique validation when we use soft delete behavior?

Tags: php, yii

In `Yii`, How is the best way to implement `unique` validation when we use `soft delete` behavior?

Currently I use custom method in model, Maybe there is another simple solution exist?
Below code still incomplete, the validation still applied when updating.

```
public function checkexists($attribute,$param) {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())  // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
        {
            $username = $this->username;
            if($username)
            {
                $Command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND status = true');

                $Command->bindParam(":username", $username);
                $user = $Command->queryAll();
                if (!empty($user))
                {
                    $this->id_user=isset($user[0]['id_user'])?$user[0]['id_user']:'';
                    $this->addError('username', 'Username exist');
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to validate something when you delete it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use yii [unique](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh21) validator for this. No need of writing an extra validation function.

Use `criteria` for additional query criteria.

```
public function rules()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->compare('status', 'true');
    return array(
        array('username', 'unique', 'criteria'=> $criteria)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to fix the custom validator that you are currently using.  You must also exclude the current user from your check.

```
$Command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND status = true AND id_user <> :id_user');

$Command->bindParam(":username", $username);
$Command->bindParam(":id_user", $this->id_user);
$user = $Command->queryAll();
```